# Passing variable from a View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the Department Id to the ActionResult in a Controller.

This is the View:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Department", "Index1","Department", new {  TestVal=item.DepartmentId  },null)
```

This is the action in Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private MYDBEntities db = new MYDBEntities(); 
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Employees.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Index1(int? TestVal)
        {
            Department d1 = db.Departments.Find(TestVal);
            return View(d1);
        }
}
```

This throws 404 error. Whats the problem...

Comment: Include your full controller class if possible.

Comment: what do you mean ?" Department" is the controller name

Comment: He means to add your controller's code @thisarawasugama

Comment: public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private MYDBEntities db = new MYDBEntities(); 
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Employees.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Index1(int? TestVal)
        {
            Department d1 = db.Departments.Find(TestVal);
            return View(d1);
        }}

Comment: @vasilisdmr Right you are.... Need to have a look on controller class some time `route declaration` may have problem.

Comment: It would much more helpful to you and other developers(in order to help you out), to edit your question and add the code there.@thisarawasugama

Comment: plz give me sec

Comment: its wrong controller ... thnk you

Comment: You have provided "Department" as controller name in `Html.ActionLink` method but `Index1` action is in Employee controller... that's why you are getting 404

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the wrong controller.

Here you are calling the `DepartmentController`

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Department", "Index1","Department", new {  TestVal=item.DepartmentId  },null)
```

When you should be calling the `EmployeeController`

Comment: yeh got it ... thnk u

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Department", "Index1","Employee", new {  TestVal=item.DepartmentId  },null)
```

Just replace "Department" with "Employee", `EmployeeController` being the one where `Index1` method exists.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation regarding how your code solves the problem.